# Command to know last reboot time in SLES

Tags: linux, sles

I have been trying to get the last system reboot time with seconds in SLES 12 version with below commands but none of them giving the time with seconds.

```
who -b
system boot  2020-07-30 23:02

last reboot
reboot   system boot  4.12.14-95.54-de Thu Jul 30 23:02 - 11:41 (3+12:39)
```

As uptime -s doesn't work in SLES, is there any command to get the last system reboot time with seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `-F / --fulltimes` of `last` to display the times including seconds.

```
last -F reboot
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Above command giving the time in seconds but how can make that out time in this format 2020-07-30 21:39:14 instead of Aug 3 13:01:46. 
last -F reboot | head -1 |awk '{print$6,$7,$8}'. -->  Aug 3 13:01:46